# Sqlite query check - less than and greater than

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, 
KEY_LEVEL }, KEY_LEVEL + ">" + "=" + 3 + "<" + 5, null, null, null, null);
```

What am I doing wrong. It's returning all over above and equal to level 3 but not less than 5. I've tried && | and such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
KEY_LEVEL + ">" + "=" + 3 + "<" + 5
```

translates as

```
KEY_LEVEL + ">=3<5"
```

Use that instead:

```
KEY_LEVEL + ">= 3 AND " + KEY_LEVEL + " < 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare KEY_LEVEL to 3 and compare KEY_LEVEL to 5 with a conjunction of two expressions. I've never seen SQL use the && or || operators; use AND and OR.