# SQLite query less than or greater than check

Tags: android, database, algorithm, sqlite

I want to use this:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, 
KEY_LEVEL }, KEY_LEVEL + ">= 3 AND " + KEY_LEVEL + " < 5", null, null, null, null);
```

But instead of 5 I want it to check the next column where it finds greater than or equal to three.

So when I give an input of say 5, I want it to check for greater than or equal to 5 in column 3 but less than the value in the next column, column 4.

Original code taken from [Sqlite query check - less than and greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692897/sqlite-query-check-less-than-and-greater-than).

Comment: Your description is incomprehensible. What is "column 3"? What is the "next column"?

Answer (score 5):

Just do this :

```
String[] selectionArgs = { "5", "5" };
String[] columns = { KEY_ROWID, KEY_COLUMN3, KEY_COLUMN4 };
String selection = "KEY_COLUMN3 >= ? AND KEY_COLUMN4 < ?";
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

For me just passing numerics in String format like @buzeeg offered **didn't work**.

**PROBLEM:** My task was to perform `UPDATE` and in my case it **should not** have succeed, but as you may guess, when we use `1` as query arg, `'1'>2` means `true`:

```
UPDATE table SET field = 1 WHERE ? > 2
```

**SOLUTION:** `CAST` helped me to solve it:

```
SELECT * FROM smth WHERE CAST(? as integer) > 2
```